# Custom tabs on android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I want to create some tabs on android but I do not know if this kind of tabs is possible to create on android. If they are possible can someone give me some link to a similar tutorial or example so I can take a look how to create such tabs in android.

Here is what I'm looking for:
I need to have 2 tabs left and right, and a logo in the center that is not clickable.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [my library on Github](https://github.com/yayaa/CustomTabsFragment) it allows you to create a custom tab layout and use it. So you can create a layout which contains both image and text, and then you can modify tab according to position.

Comment: Aaahh sorry, you don't want your textview as a tab.
So maybe you can create this view by yourself with relativeLayout; two imageviews on left, two imageviews alignParentRight and logo centered.